# Windows 7 Black Screen

Tags: windows-7

I have been living in italy for the last 2 months and my laptop has worked fine. This past weekend I went to Ireland without realizing they had different plugs and just picked up a cheap one there. The first two days it worked fine, but eventually it would come to the start page and nothing would load. Now, back in italy, when I start up in normal mode it stops after the log in at a black screen with just a cursor. I can boot to safe mode, and safe mode to connect to the internet. I have run virus scans and such through safe mode and they all come clean.

Comment: Given you can boot to safe mode I don't think the different plugs/power have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: Clean virus scans only mean you are not infected by a *known* virus.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can offer you, is to try the System Restore tool.
It sounds like some of the Windows system files are corrupted.

Try to restore your system to an earlier restore point (make sure to choose restore point that has been taken when your PC was working properly)

Answer (score 2):

A system restore is a good start. If that doesn't work, you may have to consider doing a clean install, which means you'll lose your info (lest you have a way to backup your data). There might be additional solutions here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Resolving-stop-blue-screen-errors-in-Windows-7

But those two methods seem to be the most common ones.

Answer (score 2):

Couple ideas:

1) Have you tried booting to the black screen and then using the notebook's LCD->External monitor toggle to ensure it's not trying to output to a non-existent external monitor?

2) Perhaps your video drivers are corrupted.  Hence you can boot into safe mode, but as soon as the desktop enhancements of the driver kick in (after login) it goes blank.

- Try starting Windows in "VGA" mode (F8 -> Enable low-resolution video (640×480)), this should start everything as normal, except your video driver.  If this works, then you're good to uninstall and reinstall the video drivers (go get and use the latest from your notebook manufacturer).
- If VGA Mode doesn't work, try uninstalling the driver in safe mode, and/or remove the existing display device from the Device Manager and let it re-detect on next (normal) boot.