# Windows 7 black screen after boot up

Tags: windows, windows-7, boot

When I start Windows 7 on my laptop, it starts the booting process, shows me the Windows 7 logo/flag, and then goes to a black screen, remaining that way.

I tried to use the options `safe mode`,`safe mode with command prompt` and also `safe mode with networking`, but every time I see a black screen.

Comment: This has happened to me before, and after trying a bunch of things, I just let it sit for an hour. Eventually it cleared up and never happened again.

Comment: When you boot(ed), what happens when the screen goes black? Does the HDD LED flicker? Does pressing the `-lock` keys on the keyboard toggle the `-lock` LEDs on and off?

Answer (score 1):

Most fixes for Windows Vista and this problem work on Windows 7.
Video adapter problems are the most common cause of this issue, but most black screens are trial and error. As you are not getting in at all, without any blinking cursor, and no plugged in Printers / mouse, etc you can not update your drivers.

- When you turn it off do you unplug the cable and take the battery out?
- Have you run memtest86?
- Will it run a Live CD?
- Have you installed anything new before, any new hardware?
- Do you have a system repair disk, a boot disk, install disk or complete OEM reinstall disc set?

Have you read these SU posts
[black screen 1](https://superuser.com/questions/264458/windows-7-black-screen)
[black screen 2](https://superuser.com/questions/79421/windows-7-black-screen-of-death)
Sorry i'm not much help, but there is not much good news out there.

Answer (score 1):

Press F8 and select *Repair Your Computer*:

[image]

Then do a Windows System Restore. If you do not have this option to select then make a [System Repair disc](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc) on another Windows 7 PC and boot from that disc. The PC you make the System Repair disc on must be the same bit version as the one you are repairing.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before and, believe it or not, this is how I fixed it,

```
Burned a WinPE disc
Booted into WinPE
Run "SysPrep /oobe"
```

This is the out of box experience apparently, it must clear the boot sequence or something.

Exact SysPrep:

> C:\Windows\System32\SysPrep

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to solve this mystery yesterday. At first, I tried a quick fix : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. then go to Task Manager, see if `explorer.exe` is there - delete him if he is then go to `File` -> `New Task` and type: `explorer.exe`. This was a quick fix....

But I wanted to solve this so I wouldn't have to always do this. This appear to be a registry problem so you want to either hit <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and write `regedit` then navigate the folders like this :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Microsoft -> Windows NT -> CurrentVersion -> WinLogon

Once you're on WinLogon just click WinLogon you should see Shell in the list on the right part of the window. Shell value is `explorer.exe` if it isn't...there's something wrong... Anyway I deleted Shell. Then went to `Edit` -> `New` -> `String` key you enter the same value "Shell" then click on the newly created Shell item, right click it. Modify and enter `explorer.exe` to the value.

This seems to have done it for me. I've also noted that when I created a new user I didn't get any black screen when login on the newly created user.